# How can I make `git fetch --all` fail/show me failures prominently, if any of the remotes fail?

Tags: git, git-fetch

My issue is that I have multiple remotes set up, but day to day I only push to one. Let's call this remote 'Frank'. The other one, I almost never pull from, lets call her 'Alex'.

The 'Alex' remote is reliable, 'Frank' is unreliable. He gives me:

> `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

When I run `git fetch --all -p`, if 'Frank' fails the error output gets crowded out and pushed off screen by the successful fetching of all the branches updated on 'Alex'. The issue comes, in that if I don't see that 'Frank' has failed again, I carry on gitting as though I'm up to date.

Can I make `git --all` fail if any of the remotes fail, with an extra option? The [Git Fetch Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) give the `--atomic` option, but that says:

> `--atomic`
> Use an atomic transaction to update local refs. Either all refs are updated, or on error, no refs are updated.

Now I'm not certain that would work (does a remote not being reachable tell git that a local ref failed?), but I'm being told that `atomic` is not an options, and it's not listed in the usage output. I don't and can't get my git updated currently (I'm on v2.20.1).

Is that possible, or maybe something that suppresses anything not from 'Frank' ?

Comment: Unfortunately, `--all` inside `git fetch` is still one-at-a-time with the update either happening, or not. So if Frank fails you'll still get all the Alex updates. About your only way to avoid this is to attempt the fetches one at a time yourself, in the order of most likely to least likely failure, and stop if Frank fails. That still gives you a minor problem if Frank succeeds and Alex fails; the best bet for *this* (plus the other case) is to avoid depending on both-succeeding in the first place.

Comment: @torek could a silent dry-run and then on success call the real fetch work?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the flakiness, but in general, "look, then try for real" is a recipe for problems when the "look" step works and the "try for real" one doesn't. What I find curious is why you want this kind of all-or-nothing behavior in the first place...

Comment: @torek it's mainly so I spot when one fails

Comment: Seems like just saving (and parsing?) the error output might do the trick, then.

Comment: @torek it could do but that sounds more involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-q` (or `--quiet`) to silence the success messages.
Then you're left with only error messages (if any).

```
git fetch --all -pq
```

Also the exit code will let you know whether or not there were errors.
You can use that to execute commands accordingly:

```
git fetch --all -pq && echo 'success' || echo 'FAILURE'
```

E.g. you could first run a dry-run before running a real fetch:

```
git fetch --dry-run --all -pq && git fetch --all -p
```

(However, if a remote is reachable during the dry-run, but not during the real fetch, then you won't get the desired result)

If you want to see errors AND remote branch updates (bash syntax):

```
git fetch --all -p |& grep -Ei '^( |error:|fatal:)'
```

If you only want to see errors and branch updates of remote "Frank" (bash syntax):

```
git fetch --all -p |& grep -Ei '^(error:|fatal:)|\bFrank/'
```

Comment: This is a really good answer but, if possible, I'd still like to see what has updated on 'Frank' though, I wonder if I'd better off calling two separate git fetches?

Comment: I see. I added 2 more suggestions to my answer. Maybe they'll do the trick for you?

Comment: Would a silent dry run, and then running the real-deal also work?

Comment: That's a nice idea :) If you chain dry-run and real-done together using `&&` then the real-deal should not start if the dry-run failed: `git fetch --dry-run --all -pq && git fetch --all -p`, However, if Frank should be reachable during the dry-run, but not during the actual one, you'll be none the wiser.

Comment: The dry run technique worked for me this morning

Comment: Ok cool. Glad to hear :)