# Redundant Git repositories

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to tell the Git client: pull from this remote repo, and if that's unavailable, pull from this mirror (or mirrors)? Or a way to set up a load balancer for Git?

At our company, we store our code on GitHub. And this works well most of the time - but sometimes there's an outage on GitHub, and our workflows grind to a halt, because we have multiple automated jobs running on a Jenkins cluster, and those jobs fetch the code from GitHub before running it.

We don't want to ditch GitHub, we just want a backup. One possible solution is to keep pushing code changes to GitHub, but set up a Git mirror on one of our own servers, and point the Jenkins jobs to the mirror. Downsides to that: there will be a delay before the newest code becomes available, and the mirror itself might go down. So ideally, I'd want some system that automatically tries multiple repos.

I know that Git was originally designed to work with a decentralized model (even if most people today don't use it like that, and just keep one central repo, like we did in the bad old days of CVS). So it seems to me like there should be a solution out there.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Not sure this really is a duplicate. The question is how to do that automatically, without manually running `git pull` with different remotes. Also I suspect (I saw a related Q at SO) that GIt stops processing remote URLs on the 1st error.

Comment: @phd the other question is also how to do that automatically, and apparently according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/849960/4621513, `git remote update` does that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The answer is from 2009 and I'm not sure it's still true. IWBN if someone conducted and experiment with two URLs, one wrong/inaccessible and one accessible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+multiple+remotes

Comment: @mkrieger1 It seems it's still true: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72446448/7976758 `git fetch --all` fetches all remotes and ignores errors.

Comment: The other post is not *exactly* a duplicate, but it sent me in the right direction and answered some of my questions, so it's close enough. I still need to figure out how the Jenkins Git plugin deals with all this, but I guess that's a separate issue. Thanks to all who responded.